# How do I 'workon' a Python virtualenv in Byobu windows configuration?

Tags: byobu, gnu-screen, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to configure [Byobu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byobu_%28software%29) that it will start with a few windows ready in my Python [virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) project directory. The only thing that needs to be run is the command `workon myvirtualenvname`.

What I've done now is this.

1. Selected the Screen backend using

   ```
   byobu-select-backend
   ```
2. In `~/.byobu/windows`:

   ```
   screen -t env2-1 workon env2
   screen -t env2-2 workon env2
   ```
3. Starting byobu now fails. Running

   ```
   byobu
   ```

   results in a error being shown for a short period of time:

   ```
   Cannot exec 'workon': No such file or directory
   ```

   and Byobu terminates:

   ```
   [screen is terminating]
   ```

I think the issue originates in the way the `workon` command is defined. As with the virtualenvwrapper documentation, this is being set in `~/.bashrc` by sourcing `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`. In the latter file this `workon` command is defined as a Bash function (`function workon {`).

How can I make screen/byobu start my windows as defined in the configuration despite it being Bash functions being run in there?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and virtualenv 3.6 (not on 4.x yet as I see it has some backward incompatibilities).